# ¿Como puedo sumar el contenido de un arreglo?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo un arreglo y quiero sumar todo lo que tiene adentro y meterlo en una variable.

```
<?php
$arreglo = array (1,1,1,1);
for ($i=0;$i<4; $i++){
$suma= $suma+$arreglo[i][i];
}
echo $suma;
?>
```

¿Que es lo que tengo mal?

Answer (score 3):

El problema lo tienes al momento de capturar el índice del `array` en la iteración actual del ciclo `for`, estas usando `i` cuando deberías usar la variable creada en el `for` `$i`.

```
<?php

$arreglo = array (1,1,1,1,50);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arreglo); $i++){
    $suma = $suma + $arreglo[$i];
}
echo $suma;

?>
```

Ahora como recomendación: la condición de cumplimiento del ciclo la deberías hacer con la longitud del `array` y no con un número quemado, así se te adapta a cualquier `array` que pases en el ciclo.

```
<?php

$arreglo = array(1,1,1,1,50);
echo array_sum($arreglo);;

?>
```

También podrías usar el método `array_sum()` así te evitar el `for`.

Comment: me parece muy importante donde le mencionas que no coloque un número directo en el for, sino que como muestras use `count` para la longitud del mismo; de ese modo se hace dinámico se código y funcional para otros escenarios

Answer (score 2):

No es estrictamente necesario iterar con un bucle tu arreglo de números; basta con que uses el método `array_sum` de este modo:

```
$arreglo = array (1,1,1,1);

$suma = array_sum($arreglo);

echo $suma;
```

Itera los elementos de un array y devuelve la sumatoria de todos ellos.

Answer (score 0):

PHP tiene la función `array_sum()` que ya hace eso y te llenar de for el código

```
$arreglo = array (1,1,1,1);
$suma = array_sum($arreglo);
```

más información 
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php